# Element type is invalid: React Js

Tags: reactjs

I am developing teams app using react js. I got the following error when running the application.

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `Tab`.**

Below the source code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import AgGridReact from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import AgGridColumn from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//var showFunction = Boolean(process.env.REACT_APP_FUNC_NAME);
const InitialRowData = [
{make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
{make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
{make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];
function Project() {
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(InitialRowData);
return (
 <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 400, width: 600}}>
   <AgGridReact
            rowData={rowData}
            >
            <AgGridColumn field="make"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="model"></AgGridColumn>
            <AgGridColumn field="price"></AgGridColumn>
       </AgGridReact>
 </div>
 );
 }
const element = <Project></Project>
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Your imports from ag-grid-react needs to be named imports, not default imports. Eg, `import { AgGridReact, AgGridColumn } from 'ag-grid-react';`

Comment: If i change it to named imports, its throwing me differant error.Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `columns` the same way you are adding the `rows`

```
const columnDefs = [
   { field: 'athlete' },
   { field: 'sport' },
   { field: 'age' },
];

const [columnData, setColumnData] = useState(InitialColumnData);
```

And then set it in `return` the same way you set `rows`

Comment: I tried this one also but i got same error.

Comment: Also this error is throwing when i add column using a ag grid column in return code.. When i replace them with normal paragraph tag or h tag its running without any error.

Comment: ok I will check what's the error

Comment: Try creating the `columns` the same way you create `rows`

Comment: Check out my answer I'm editing it.

Comment: This one also not working. Tried same way as you mentioned above and its throwing same error.